# how find the position of hole in a harmonic image?

Tags: python, image, detection

I try to find the defect or changes in an image of regular shape so as this

I want to find the position of deformation in it that it may change its position so as this

I try to do this by pixel of the image and the position of the x and y coordination in python

```
    imgdata = image.getdata()
    imgWidth, imgHeight = image.size
    x_pos = 0
    y_pos = 1
    pixel_value = []
    x = []
    y = []
    
    for item in imgdata:
        item = str(item)
    
        if (x_pos) == imgWidth:
            x_pos = 1
            y_pos += 1
        else:
            x_pos += 1
    
        if item[1] != 0:
            pixel_value.append(item[0])
            x.append(x_pos)
            y.append(y_pos)
    
    pixel_value, x, y = zip(*sorted(zip(pixel_value, x, y), reverse=True))

df = pd.DataFrame({'target':pixel_value,'X': x,  'Y': y })
```

but this locates the pixel and pixel location and I can not find the position of hols?
I would be grateful if any recommend the best way to find the hols
thanks a lot

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical rule that would tell you where the dark pixels are (or at least some of them), if there is *no* hole? Then, the hole is in the place where there *would* be a pixel, but isn't.

Comment: the x and y position of pixels is clear and the holes are put randomly in the image I looking to find the image processing for finding the holes x and y and if the possible radius of them.

Comment: By the way, if you are generating these images in code, you really should think about using PNG rather than JPG - there will be far fewer artefacts and your values will stay as they are rather than getting smeared, distorted and blurred as JPEGs.

Comment: thank you for your advice and yes of course I change it to grayscale for better processing

Answer (score 0):

You could try repeatedly flood-filling, say with red, starting at many seed points across your image and then count the number of red pixels resulting. It will be bigger in the *"holes"* and you could then find the area and centroid of the red pixels.

You would have to distribute your seed points to be all across your image probably at distances smaller than the radius of your current white lattice holes.

[image]

I don't think this approach will be that fast, so you may want to use multiprocessing.

---

You could also look at the sums of the pixels across the rows (and/or columns) of your image by making your image into a Numpy array and then using:

```
rowSums = np.sum(image, axis=1)
```

[image]

Where there are holes in your lattice, there will be more white pixels and fewer black pixels in a row, the sums will therefore tend to be higher.

Comment: thank you for recommend but flood filling is better for close loop rather than loops that when I change to the grayscale the boundaries between the shape erase, does it true? and because I have about 2000 images is it fast?

Comment: Your boundaries probably disappear because you have used JPEG and the black boundaries smudge and blur and get lost. I added a PNG example.

Comment: a very attractive method similar to your way I am creating a dataset of the images with different position holes and by having the x, y, and pixel values train with machine learning algorithm, what do you think? of course, I must check your methods. Do you have any recommend python code for the two programs above (filling and sum pixel)?

Comment: Both are one-liners. The floodfill is just a matter of calling `cv2.floodFill()` and I already showed in my answer how to sum across the rows with `np.sum()`.

Comment: by the sum of the pixel, I can take the similar way as you because I'm in a first way, now I have the sum of pixel max in row and column how I can reach the x and y coordination of a range of maximum pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

by the sum of the pixel, I can take the similar way as you because I'm in a first way, now I have the sum of pixel max in row and column how I can reach the x and y coordination of a range of maximum pixel values? I mean does any recommend for calculating the range of increasing in the charts?